# Building a verbose regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex that depend on variables that are coming from from many different sources.

sources:

```
dict1 = {"a":"somevalue","b":"somevalue","c":"somevalue"}
source2 = "x"
source3 = "_1"
```

I want to build a regex that will depend on the values that I will get from the above sources.
 the resulting regex will look like below.

```
^(a|b|c)x[0-9]{0,10}_1
```

where:

- `(a|b|c)` is the keys of `dict1` and `dict` can have one or more values.
- `x` is the value from `source2`.
- `-1` is the value that I will get from the `source3`.

I am not satisfied with the solution that I have which is basically concatenation the sources to build the regex. I was wondering if there is any other better and good solution. Here is the solution that I came up with.

```
group1 = "|".join(dict1.keys())
regex = "^("+group1+")"+source2+"[0-9]{0,10}"+source3
```

Will appreciate your help. May be `re.verbose`? But I am not sure whats the best way.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Just make sure to [escape](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) properly, should your input contain reserved characters, e.g. `source2 = "."`

Comment: Just minor tweaks on the basic idea: `regex = "^(%s)%s[0-9]{0,10}%s" % ("|".join(dict1), source2, source3)`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the expression is simple enough you can also avoid regular expression escape headaches by parsing manually:

```
def parse(s):
    assert max(len(k) for k in dict1) == 1 and len(source2) == 1 #keep it simple

    match = (s[0:1] in dict1 and 
        s[1:2] == source2 and
        all(c in string.digits for c in s[2:-2]) and
        len(s[2:-2]) <= 10 and
        s[-2:] == source3)
    return s[0] if match else None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use htql.RegEx at http://htql.net.  Something like this:

```
import htql; 
a=htql.RegEx(); 
a.setNameSet('group1', dict1.keys() )
a.setNameSet('x', [source2])
a.setNameSet('x1', [source3])
results=a.reSearchStr(address, "^&[s:group1]&[s:x][0-9]{0,10}&[s:x1]", case=False);
```